# Selecting specific data from an Ansible register

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, vpc

I'd really appreciate some help on correctly selecting data from a register in ansible.
The following code *almost* works... :)

I create an AWS VPC here, I register the information in 'vpc'. 
I then refer to vpc.

```
  - name: Create VPC and Subnets
    ec2_vpc:
      state: present
      cidr_block: '{{ ip-range}}'
      resource_tags: { "Name": "{{ vpc_name }}" }
      region: '{{ region }}'
      subnets:
        - cidr: '{{ pub-subneta }}'
          az: '{{ region }}a'
          resource_tags: { "Name": "Public Subnet 1" }

        - cidr: '{{ pub-subnetb }}'
          az: '{{ region }}b'
          resource_tags: { "Name": "Public Subnet 2" }

        - cidr: '{{ priv-subnet1 }}'
          az: '{{ region }}a'
          resource_tags: { "Name": "Private Subnet 1" }

        - cidr: '{{ priv-subnet2 }}'
          az: '{{ region }}b'
          resource_tags: { "Name": "Private Subnet 2" }
      internet_gateway: True
    register: vpc
```

That works well. It creates the VPC with the 4 subnets. 
I then want to launch a NAT instance in a specific subnet which I tried to do by specifiying the subnet as follows:

```
- name: Create NAT instance
  ec2:
    state: present
    key_name: '{{ ssh_key_name }}'
    instance_type: '{{ nat_instance_type }}'
    image: '{{ nat_ami }}'
    region: '{{ region }}'
    wait: yes
    instance_tags:
      Name: "natsrv01"
      Description: "NAT Server"
    assign_public_ip: yes
    source_dest_check: false
    vpc_subnet_id: '{{ vpc.subnets[0].id }}'
```

This is where it doesn't work as intended. 
I'd assumed that the register would contain invformation in the order it was defined/created but that's not the case.

Using debug I can see that the 4 subnets are in a random order in the register. e.g. on one attempt "Public Subnet 2" was identified by 'vpc.subnets[0].id' and on another attempt "private Subnet 2" was the first in the list.

Can someone suggest how I can reliably & repeatedly select "Public Subnet 1" from the register please?

The full output of the vpc register is:

```
 ok: [localhost] => {
 "vpc": {
     "changed": true,
     "invocation": {
         "module_args": "",
         "module_name": "ec2_vpc"
     },
     "subnets": [
         {
             "az": "eu-west-1b",
             "cidr": REDACTED,
             "id": "subnet-REDACTED",
             "resource_tags": {
                 "Name": "Private Subnet B"
             }
         },
         {
             "az": "eu-west-1c",
             "cidr": REDACTED,
             "id": "subnet-REDACTED",
             "resource_tags": {
                 "Name": "Private Subnet C"
             }
         },
         {
             "az": "eu-west-1a",
             "cidr": REDACTED,
             "id": "subnet-REDACTED",
             "resource_tags": {
                 "Name": "Public Subnet A"
             } 
         },
         {
             "az": "eu-west-1c",
             "cidr": REDACTED,
             "id": "subnet-REDACTED",
             "resource_tags": {
                 "Name": "Public Subnet C"
             }
         },
         {
             "az": "eu-west-1b",
             "cidr": REDACTED,
             "id": "subnet-REDACTED",
             "resource_tags": {
                 "Name": "Public Subnet B"
             }
         },
         {
             "az": "eu-west-1a",
             "cidr": REDACTED,
             "id": "subnet-REDACTED",
             "resource_tags": {
                 "Name": "Private Subnet A"
             }
         }
     ], 
     "vpc": {
         "cidr_block": "REDACTED",
         "dhcp_options_id": "dopt-53eb0f36",
         "id": "vpc-REDACTED",
         "region": "eu-west-1",
         "state": "pending"
     },
     "vpc_id": "vpc-REDACTED"
 }
}
```

Comment: can you post full contents of variable `vpc`? e.g. add task `- debug: var=vpc`

Comment: Thanks Kashyap.
I've updated the original Question with the full output of vpc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
- name: Find the first public subnet
  set_fact: vpc_subnet_id="{{ item.id }}"
  when: item.resource_tags.Name == "Public Subnet 1"
  with_items: vpc.subnets
```

Comment: edited answer based on @Kashyap comment (which is correct. there is no module called 'vpc_subnet_id', we should use set_fact to set a new variable.)

Comment: Thank you so much. This provided exactly the behaviour I was after. 

I don't have enough credit to 'vote up' your answer otherwise I would have. 

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You could also try writing a subnet filter as follows:

```
vpc_subnet_id: "{{ vpc.subnets | subnet_name_filter() }}"
```

Create a file /ansible_plugins/filter_plugins/core.py with this:

```
def subnet_name_filter(list):
  return [x for x in list if x.resource_tags.Name == "Public Subnet 1"]

class FilterModule(object):
  def filters(self):
    return {          
      'subnet_name_filter': subnet_name_filter
    }
```

Edit ansible.cfg, and [uncomment the line](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/ansible.cfg#L120) where we enable custom filter_plugins. That path can be relative, and ansible will look for the plugins relative to the place where ansible.cfg was found. I have my ansible.cfg and all plugins checked into my git repo for example.

Edit:

You could also remove hard coding in the custom plugin if you refactor like:

```
def subnet_name_filter(list, restagname):
  return [x for x in list if x.resource_tags.Name == restagname]
```

and use

```
vpc_subnet_id: "{{ vpc.subnets | subnet_name_filter('Public Subnet 1') }}"
```

Comment: I always hated the way ansible forces us to create such useless/specific-to-my-case-number-4521 filter_plugins.

Comment: All of [jinja's builtin filters](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#builtin-filters) are also ansible filter plugins. But unfortunately all of jinja's [builtin tests](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#builtin-tests) are not in ansible. Some of those tests have been implemented as filters like | skipped failed changed etc. Modelling a test as a filter seems wrong and leads to all this verbose code.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to proivde an answer, this is useful to me since I'm learning python at the moment.
Thanks very much for your help.